# converting to correct format for plotting

Tags: r

Rookie R person here, trying to plot
I have:

```
str(chrs)

chr [1:391048] "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT" "MT" 

str(comps2$X1.7)

num [1:391048] 0.0147 0.019 0.0301 0.032 0.0492
```

I am not sure how to convert the chrs to the appropriate format for `plot(chrs,comps2$X1.7, type="l")`

I have tried `chrs <- as.numeric(as.character(chrs))` and `chrs <- as.numeric(chrs)` but this just introduces NAs

I want the graph to look like the first one below but with the x-axis labels as the second graph which is what I get when using plot `plot(as.factor(chrs), comps2$X1.7, ylim = c(0,1), type = "l")`

I know there's an simple fix. Any help is much appreciated.

Extra awesome would be if anyone knows how to have the background change from white to gray with every change in X-axis label, but would rather have a working plot first :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you want `plot(as.factor(chrs), comps2$X1.7, type = "l")`?

Comment: @Shree Close! But I'm getting the right x-axis labels now (i.e. chr) but instead of a line plot there is a box plot within each group (ie MT).

Comment: how does a line plot with character as x-axis make sense? In what order would you join the points?

Answer (score 0):

I used the `ggplot2` package. You have to define a `dataframe` first because the `ggplot` function takes a dataframe as Input. You can then define the x values as the indices from 1 to the max index of your value vector and then change the labels on the x axis with `scale_x_continous`:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(chrs = chrs, values = comps2$X1.7, color = 1:2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1:nrow(df), y = values)) + 
 geom_line() + 
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:length(df$chrs),
                  labels = df$chrs)
```

EDIT: To change the colors just add a color indicator to the dataframe and alternate it between 1 and 2. You can then pass it to the **aesthetics** of the `geom_line` function (they need to be a `factor` in this case) and define your colors in the `scale_color_manual`.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(chrs = chrs, values = comps2$X1.7, color = 1:2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1:nrow(df), y = values)) + 
 geom_line(aes(col = as.factor(df$color))) + 
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:length(df$chrs),
                  labels = df$chrs) +
 scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @FloSchmo. Do you know how to do this with R? having 1's for "group1", 2s for group2, 1s for "group3" and so on?